# Working out the area of Australia through Calculus?

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, parametric, surface-integrals

I was wondering if it would be possible, and if so how, to calculate the area of an abstract shape on a sphere using surface integrals and Parametric surfaces and such.

I am looking in to this as part of my assignment and I am not sure how to approach this problem.

Comment: Please see the [Help Center FAQ](http://math.stackexchange.com/help) for how to ask good questions.  Our strong suit is math-based problems that have fairly concise and justifiable solutions.  Opening a broad topic for discussion may not get the general advice you request.  You will perhaps improve the Question if you ask about analytic modelling of a specific geo dataset you plan to use, or find some other way to narrow the Question.

Comment: Sorry, I was not aware of this, I am new to the site. I'll see what I can do to improve the question.

Comment: Sure, part of what you might fill in is the background of the Question.  It would be helpful to know how detailed you want your model to be.